Transmitted Audio (phone) Is barely understandable. How to pinpoint the cause
This evening while talking with KB1QYH, he ponted out that my audio sounded badly. It sounds like it's being put through a guitar's Wah Wah pedal.
I've reconfirmed this by broadcasting on W1BBV's IC-746PRO and listening on our Kenwood.
Both transceivers are grounded. The ICOm is transmitting to a roof-mounted MFJ 6-20m vertical antenna.
I'm stumped as to where to go from here.
Additional information:
20m 14.243.05
Icom IC-SMA microphone
Same result with microphone gain and RF power turned down.
There is slightly more audio clarity with microphone gain turned down on ten meters.

Is there a compressor or some other audio processor you can turn on and off to troubleshoot?

Does this still happen when you reduce your TX power? Maybe RF is getting into your mic or audio.

You need to provide more information: Band, mode, what type of mic you're using? Did you try changing to the stock hand mic? Are you using an amplifier? How long have you operated your current setup with no issues? What type of power supply are you using? Have you checked your coax connections? These are all external factors that can impact audio...and for audio issues, grounding your radio is not nearly as important as shielding your mic cord.

I've just spoken to Montreal from Peabody MA, and contact there said OK on audio quality
